# Комбинация элементов списка в группы определённого размера

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть исходный список `['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 's', 'B', 's', 'B', 's', 's', 's']`. Элемент `B` имеет условный размер 2, элемент `s` - размер 1.
Нужно собрать из него новый список с порядком, максимально приближенному к изначальному, но чтобы внутри элементы выстраивались в группы размера `n` (целое число - например, 4).

Т.е. чтобы результат имел вид примерно такой:

```
[('B', 'B'), ('B', 'B'), ('B', 'B'), ('s', 's', 'B'), ('s', 's', 's')]
                                ^замена^              ^-- остатки --^
```

Ну, и изначальный список может быть любым.
И размер групп `n` тоже.

Может есть какой-то математический алгоритм для подобных задач?
И в каком-нить `numpy` / `pandas` уже есть реализация?

Comment: что вызывает замену? какое условие?

Comment: размер элемента. т.е. конечная группа должна иметь размер `n`.Т.к. `('B', 's')` имеет размер 3, а `('B', 's', 'B')` уже 5, то меняем `'B'` и `'s'`.

Comment: замена может уходить через один элемент? т.е. поменяться не с ближайшим соседом а через несколько?

Comment: да через сколько угодно, но итоговый список должен максимально быть похож на изначальный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код избыточен малёк, но выполняет то, что вам нужно вроде. Наборы символов назвал `Box`. Они бывают полные и не полные. Проходя по входному списку пытаемся добавить в какую-нибудь неполную коробку, не выходит создаём новую, если вышло то переводим неполную коробку в разряд полных и т.д.

Можно менять входной список, словарь весов и размер коробки (`max_n`).

P.S. поч ответы разные.
В вашем примере ответа, есть еще приоритеты на замену - я их не реализовал. Тип если соседа прибавить и не получается полная коробка - выкидываем и ищем пока не получится полная.

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self, n,  number, dict_):
        self.nn = n
        self.id = number
        self.item = []
        self.values = dict_

    def count(self):
        return sum([self.values[a] for a in self.item])

    def add(self, i):
        p = 0
        if (self.count() + self.values[i]) <= self.nn:
            self.item.append(i)
            p = 1
        if self.count() == self.nn:
            p = 2
        return p

input_list = ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 's', 'B', 's', 'B', 's', 's', 's']
# Словарь весов
dict_v = {'B': 2, 's': 1}
max_n = 4

# лист готовых коробок
box_list = []
# лист неготовых коробок >> в конце добавить к остатку
sub_box_list = []
# id коробок
id_box = [k for k in range(len(input_list))]

for i in input_list:
    if bool(sub_box_list):
        len_s_b_list = len(sub_box_list)
        for i_s_b in range(len_s_b_list):
            j = sub_box_list[i_s_b].add(i)
            if j > 0:
                if j > 1:
                    d = sub_box_list.pop(i_s_b)
                    box_list.append(d)
                break
    else:
        box = Box(max_n, id_box.pop(), dict_v)
        j = box.add(i)
        if j == 2:
            box_list.append(box)
        elif j == 1:
            sub_box_list.append(box)
        else:
            print "fail"

print [v.item for v in box_list] + [v.item for v in sub_box_list]
# [['B', 'B'], ['B', 'B'], ['B', 's', 's'], ['B', 's', 's'], ['s']]
```

Comment: ваш код у меня с ходу не заработал: на случайных наборах неправильно формировал конечный список. Но он лёг в основу вот этого кода: https://pastebin.com/34MZ2tHQ

Comment: и теперь я в раздумьях. Ваш код не полностью подходит под решение моей задачи (т.е. не пометить, как решение здесь), но без вас я бы не смог двигаться в правильном направлении...

Comment: Приятно, что не напрасно, а чем то помог. Смотрите, пометка закрывает вопрос, т.е. пользователь применил новую информацию и решил свою проблему, если не помечать - вопрос останется открытым.